# How to specify a promoter in de novo gene synthesis service?

Tags: molecular-biology, gene-expression, cloning, plasmids

I am trying to use a de novo gene synthesis service (Genscript) and one part confuses me:

Where do I pick the choice of promoter? Or is the promoter choice automatic based on my plasmid choice?

e.g. Say I want a regulable promoter (say lac induced by IPTG) how do I specify it? https://www.genscript.com/account/gene_services_gene_synthesis.html

I was given to understand in a related question that with a commercial gene you essentially just "pick the promoter you want"? Or must I somehow manually edit the gene sequence I have to incorporate the promoter I want?

[How to put a gene under the control of a regulable promoter?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/48384/how-to-put-a-gene-under-the-control-of-a-regulable-promoter/48385#48385)

I can definitely email Genscript in case it is not a part of their default interface but I just wanted to verify my understanding of the matter before I do so.

***PS.*** I even checked out Fischer's GeneArt service & even that interface has nowhere for me to select a specific promoter. Makes me wonder if I am getting the workflow wrong?

[image: Screen-shot of sequence selection from Genscript]

Comment: Wouldn't their sales team be able to help out?

Comment: @James Sure. I will email them. I just wanted to confirm that my understanding of the workflow is right. i.e. That I ought to "pick a promoter" when ordering the plasmid rather than manually modify my gene sequence before I submit.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this service. I don't think it's a bad question to ask them if their site is unclear.

Comment: @James Thanks. I've emailed them. Are you familiar with any alternative gene synthesis services? Do you remember if they offer a option to select a promoter? In any case, thanks for confirming that my question isn't too silly or obvious to ask them!

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the promoter should be specified by the cloning plasmid.

Comment: Thanks @MarchHo. Do you mean that as soon as I indicate my choice of the pUC57 plasmid that automatically fixes my promoter? If so, what's the promoter for the pUC57 plasmid, any idea?

Comment: If you need to add a promoter in an unusual location, you can add it into the synthesized DNA sequence. But normally that's decided by the cloning plasmid. If you put in the right restriction sites you can put your synthesized DNA into any cloning plasmid you want.

Comment: @user137 Thanks. No, I don't think I need a promoter at an unusual location. All I need is a regulatable promoter. I was thinking of using the lac promoter & induction using IPTG but none of the gene synthesis sites I checked out seem to offer an option to let me indicate my promoter choice. That is what is confusing me.

Comment: @user137  Perhaps there is a default promoter for the pUC57 plasmid? But I am not sure which promoter that would be.

Comment: I would start with the [pUC57 sequence](https://www.genewiz.com/File/GENEWIZ_pUC57_Plasmid_Map.pdf). I would check with your manufacturer just in case their plasmid has a different sequence. If the promoter isn't one you like, plan to move your gene into a better plasmid.

Comment: @user137 Thanks that helped a lot. So the lacZ shows it is lac promoted & IPTG induction ought to work! http://www.genscript.com/gsfiles/techfiles/GenScript_pUC57-Simple_Plasmid_Map.pdf

Comment: Usually you should provide the entire sequence that you want to have (including promoter, polyA sites etc). They will clone this sequence in a plasmid and give it to you. They generally do not check for expression or any other function. That's your job. They just ensure that the sequence provided is correctly synthesized and cloned.

Comment: Just a comment about the PolyA sites, they are not the same as PolyA sequences. If you try to put 20 or more Adenosine in a row they will refuse to synthesize it. Our lab has made plasmids with "120", "240", or "360" adenosine PolyA tails built in, but these are our best estimates because producing these oligos is hard, and sequencing them is almost impossible.